# Can't CSS select last (or first) word

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class, pth

I need to CSS select the last word. Tried ::nth-last-word and ::last-word - dosent do anything at all.

```css
.site-title a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.site-title a::last-word {
  color: #c73434;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-title">
  <a href="#">first word</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no such selector.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin - Did you actually read the post on css-tricks ? *Please note that most of the code below is not valid. It's example code. Like "wouldn't it be cool if" code.* - Check out the following pen: https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx